# Disable "secure_file_priv" in MySQL server

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I am trying to disable `secure_file_priv`.

What I have done so far:

I've added this to my `.cnf` file:

```
secure_file_priv=""
```

and restarted the `mysql` service. It had no effect.

I also tried to add it to a new file: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` because this file does not exist in my system and I found a lot of people that mention it during my research. The problem is that even with `sudo` access I can't add it.

Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Where did you add `secure_file_priv=""`? It needs to be in the `[mysqld]` section of your `my.cnf` file.

Comment: @siloko You're right, adding  it at the end of configuration file has no effect